# How do I apply the look of one item to another item?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have heard that it is possible in Guild Wars 2 to apply the look of one item to another item. In World of Warcraft this is caused transmogrification, but from what I've heard this behaves more like 'Casting' in The Secret World in that the original item is destroyed in the process.

I want to transfer the look of an Avenger's Short Bow (which in my case is a level 45 item, but it shares an appearance with an exotic bow with a different name) to a level 80 bow I have crafted.

What steps do I have to take to transfer the look of one item to another, and does it destroy the original item (the one whose image you are transferring)?

Additional, what is this *called* in Guild Wars 2?

Comment: Transmutation. Transmuted items will identify themselves as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they are called transmutation stones and they come in two varieties. Level 1-79 stones and Level 80 stones [more info can be found here](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Transmutation). The only difference is that the level 1-79 stones can only be used on gear below level 80 while the level 80 stones can be used on anything. I have found them mostly through daily achievement chests though there may be other ways to acquire them as well.
When you combine the two items you pick the look/name, stats, and slots of the new item. The process destroys both old items leaving you with your new shiny combined item.

Comment: You can buy them for real money in the cosmetic store.

Comment: Wow this window looks scary, which way around do I put the items?

Comment: Ah nevermind, it's not that scary, got it sorted now! Thanks a lot

Comment: @pixel If I remember correctly (I have not played in a while) drop each item in to a side, it does not matter which, then just click on the stat you want for each category. As you click it will start forming your new item, the selected stats will move to the middle.

Comment: I've found that transmutation stones sometimes turn up as map completion rewards; you'll get several for completing each capital city.